# How to access elements (like buttons & labels) in a UITableViewHeader?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewHeader using XIB.I can see this header on top of my table View.

I am loading the header in this way:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
   UIView *headerView = nibs[0];
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
   return headerView;
 }
```

Now I have placed buttons inside this XIB that I am loading above.How to declare actions to these buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it after this line:

```
UIView *headerView = nibs[0];
```

But instead of UIView you should use name of your UIView subclass, inside which all buttons are declared as properties.